# Spring-hibernate mapping problem

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hibernate-mapping

I have a spring-hibernate application which is failing to map an object properly: basically I have 2 domain objects, a `Post` and a `User`.  The semantics are that every Post has 1 corresponding User.

The `Post` domain object looks roughly as follows:

```
class Post {

  private int pId;
  private String attribute;
  ...
  private User user;

  //getters and setters here

}
```

As you can see, `Post` contains a reference to `User`. When I load a `Post` object, I want to corresponding `User` object to be loaded (lazily - only when its needed).

My mapping looks as follows:

```
<class name="com...Post" table="post">
    <id name="pId" column="PostId" />
    <property name="attribute" column="Attribute" type="java.lang.String" />

    <one-to-one name="User" fetch="join"
        class="com...User"></one-to-one>
</class>
```

And of course I have a basic mapping for `User` set up.

As far as my table schema is concerned, I have a table called `post` with a foreign `UserId` which links to the `user` table.

I thought this setup should work, BUT when I load a page that forces the lazy loading of the `User` object, I notice the following Hiberate query being generated:

```
Select ... from post this_ left outer join user user2_ on this.PostId=user2_.UserId ...
```

Obviously this is wrong: it should be joining `UserId` from `post` with `UserId` from `user`, but instead its incorrectly joining `PostId` from `post` (its primary key) with `UserId` from `user`.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

**Update**:
Thanks to a couple of the posts below I now realize that I should have been using a many-to-one mapping instead of a one-to-one.  I changed the mapping under `post` to the following:

```
<many-to-one name="User" class="com...User" column="uId"/>
```

But now I get a run-time error telling me that there is no attribute called `uId`.  This makes sense since I do not have a `uId` column in my `post` domain object (I simply have a reference to a `user` object).  Now I am really confused as to how I can get Hibernate to realize that it needs to map the *foreign key* from the post table to the user table.  Should explicitly add a `uId` attribute to my `post` domain object to be a *placeholder* for the foreign key?

I hope I am making sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a user has many posts, your association is in fact a "many-to-one", not a "one-to-one". It should work if you map it accordingly.

**Edit**: Yes, you can map the property Post.user on the Post with a "many-to-one", or the set User.posts in User with a "one-to-many", or both. Have you specified the name of your foreign key column?

**Edit2**: In Hibernate speak, a "column" in the database is mapped to a "property" in your Java-Class. That is, the column attribute contains the name of your foreign key column in the database, not the name of any property in your Java class. If I read your question right, you should use "UserId", not "uId".

Oh, and a fetch="join" can not be lazy, as it mandates that the user is fetched in the same query as the post.

Comment: Thanks, but is it correct to place this mapping in the "post" mapping?  I tried this with similar incorrect results.  I am not sure how to get it to join on UserId from the Post table since my domain objects don't have any notion of a foreign key, just a reference to a User object.

Comment: Thanks for your update, can you please elaborate what you mean by "have you specified the name of your foreign key column?", as I suspect that this could be my problem?

Comment: Thank you!!! I have wasted so much time on this...as you probably guessed I am new to hibernate...

Answer (score 0):

That is the behaviour of a one-to-one mapping. They usually share a primary key. Hibernate is assuming that the primary key of post is teh same as the primary key of user. [This page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone) summarizes this behaviour.

I suspect that one user can actually have more than one posts though. That makes your mapping a one-to-many.

Comment: You are right about a user having more than 1 post.  I am just confused as to where to place this mapping: under the mapping for Post or under the mapping for User?